# Copy-Paste C# style function with attributes

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have the following function:

```
[Test]
public void Some_Unit_Test_Function()
{
   // some setup-test-assert code
   ...
   // end of code
}
```

What's the 'vim' way of copying the entire function (including the [Test] attribute), and pasting it below the original function with one line spacing in-between.  I want to end up with the following:

```
[Test]
public void Some_Unit_Test_Function()
{
   // some setup-test-assert code
   ...
   // end of code
}

[Test]
public void Some_Unit_Test_Function()
{
   // some setup-test-assert code
   ...
   // end of code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `yapGo<C-o>p`:

1. `yap` to copy the paragraph
2. `G` go to the end of file
3. `o` to insert a new line and enter insert mode
4. `<C-o>` to enter another command, [more about this here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Ctrl-O_instead_of_Esc_in_insert_mode_mappings)
5. and `p` to paste

#### Updated

- Thank you for your comment @DBenKnoble, this answer now reflects entering insert mode
- @Eternal21 step 3 shows a way to enter the new line

Hope this helps. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: With `yapG` you arent in insert mode, so just follow with `p`. And in insert mode, `<C-r>"` works as well

Comment: I accepted your answer as solution.  One question though, after I press 'G' I end up on the closing bracket of the first function, so when I paste the new function I end up with no empty line between the two functions.  What's the fastest way to get that line in there?  For now I end up doing this:  yapGo<Esc>p